# IntelliJ - How to define a project SDK where each developer has a different SDK for it?

Tags: intellij-idea

We have numerous developers and we all tend to have a slightly different version of the JDK (whatever was latest when we last updated). We're all 1.8, but the x in 1.8.x.x is all over the place.

Is there a way we can define the JDK to use in our project so it is defined in files that are not part of the project and therefore not checked in? And more importantly, are not overwriting our individual choices when pulling the latest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just name your project/module JDK 'JDK', everyone then can point it to wherever they want.
[image]

Comment: Where/how do we name it? I tried changing the name but it forced it back to the JDK version.